# Retrieving correct data from the database using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve data from the database however I am not getting right results. It looks like my "If" statements are not working properly as I am getting some data from the "$sale->whereRaw" query which is at the beginning of foreach. What I am doing wrong?

I am working with Laravel 4.2.

Controller:

```
        $matches = Match::where('PeopleID', '=', $id);

        $sales = Sale::leftJoin('property', 'sales.property_id', '=', 'property.property_id')
            ->where('Status', '=', 'ForSale');


        foreach($matches as $match)
        {
            $county = $match->county;

            $sales->whereRaw("match (`county`) against (?)", array($county));

            if($match->tenureFh == '1')
            {
                $sales->where('Tenure','=','FH');

                if($match->minPrice != '0')
                {
                    $sales->where('PriceFreehold', '>=' , $match->minPrice);
                }

                if($match->maxPrice != '0')
                {
                    $sales->where('PriceFreehold', '<=', $match->maxPrice);
                }

            }

            if($match->tenureLh == '1')
            {
                $sales->where('Tenure', '=', 'LH');


                if($match->minPrice != '0')
                {
                    $sales->where('PriceLeasehold', '>=' , $match->minPrice);
                }

                if($match->maxPrice != '0')
                {
                    $sales->where('PriceLeasehold', '<=', $match->maxPrice);
                }

            }
        }


        $results = $sales->orderBy('sales.updated_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Match Model

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('People', 'PeopleID', 'PeopleID');
}

public function sale()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Sale');
}
```

Sale Model

```
public function match()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Match');
}
```

People Model

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Match', 'PeopleID', 'PeopleID');
}

public function sale()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Sale');
}
```

**@uptade**

Currently I am getting the results from this statement:

```
$sales->whereRaw("match (`county`) against (?)", array($county));
```

Which is good however I need to filter the results further and this is where the "if" statements come in to place.

"Match" contains different searching credentials for each customer. If the candidate is looking for product with "Tenure: FH" In county "A" I need to display products with county "A" and which "Tenure" is "FH" (That is why I have made some those "if" statements).  However those statements does not seem to work as I am getting  ALL results for county "A" which "Tenure" is "FH" or other than "FH".

So the problem must be with those "Ifs" as they are not filtering the result further.

Imagine you have signed in with cars dealership website and you are looking for a red, 4 door car however the result you are getting is ALL 4 door cars but with all different colours (but you wanted a red one right?) - This is how it works at the moment.

Comment: I think it'd be good to tell us what's your expected result and the result you're currently getting?

Comment: @SteD Could you see my update please. I have edited my post and explained there. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` to see what query you get in the end.

Comment: It would be easier to just say something like: dd($sales->toSql()); before the get(); and this answer does not offer a solution to this problem, although it will help debug the question.